# How can I deal with Makefile syntax error made by "tab"?

Tags: shell, makefile, tabs

I am not familiar with shell.  I just want to successfully run this piece of code which I downloaded from Github.  When I directly ran the code with the command,

> make file='example.txt' file_test

it didn't work, and here is the error.

> makefile line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I tried to fix the problem by unifying the encoding format of 'Makefile.sh' and 'example.txt' to be Unix, but still it did not work at all.

Then I asked my friend(he is also new to shell), and he told me to delete the "tab" before each line(not including the command lines).  The error is different at this time, but I still could not fix it by using Google.

> Makefile:75: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.

Please, somebody can help?  It is driving me crazy and I have no time left for solving this problem. :(  Thanks!!!

And, here is the code after I deleted the 'TAB'.

```
# State-of-the-art paper: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P18-1016


########################################Definitions########################################

SHELL := /bin/bash
NC := \033[0m
RED := \033[0;31m
GREEN := \033[0;32m
CYAN := \033[0;36m

work_dir := $(PWD)
script_dir := $(work_dir)/scripts
NTS_dir := $(work_dir)/NeuralTextSimplification_model

file?=""
filetype := $(shell file $(file) | cut -d: -f2)

article_name := $(basename $(notdir $(file)))
article_simple := $(basename $(file))-simple.txt
NTS_script := $(NTS_dir)/src/scripts/translate.sh
NTS_input := $(NTS_dir)/data/test.en
NTS_result_file = $(NTS_dir)/results_NTS/result_NTS_epoch11_10.19.t7_5

# passage = xml file representing a sentence parsed with TUPA
sentence_dir = $(script_dir)/sentences/$(article_name)
passage_dir = $(script_dir)/passages/$(article_name)
sentences = $(sentence_dir)/*.txt
passages = $(passage_dir)/*.xml


############################################################################################

.SILENT:
.ONESHELL: # To execute all commands in one single bash shell
.PHONY: all file_test NTS DSS tupa_parse split_to_sentences help clean


all: file_test $(article_simple)
    printf "\n${GREEN}Article simplified :\n====================${NC}\n\n"
    cat $(article_simple)


# evaluate the system results using BLUE & SARI metrics
# The original test.en must be given to evaluate (https://github.com/senisioi/NeuralTextSimplification)
evaluate: all
    printf "\n${GREEN}Evaluating: (the original test.en must be given)${NC}\n\n"
    python $(NTS_dir)/src/evaluate.py $(NTS_input) $(NTS_dir)/data/references/references.tsv $(NTS_dir)/predictions


############################################################################################

# The following targets are only useful as aliases for testing

# Generates the corresponding NTS model result file.
NTS: file_test $(NTS_result_file)

# Generates the article sentences split using the two semantic rules mentioned in the paper.
DSS: file_test $(NTS_input)

# Parses the article's sentences using TUPA -> output : xml files
tupa_parse: file_test $(passages)

# Splits the article into sentences, each one in a single file
split_to_sentences: file_test $(sentences)


#############################################################################################


# Testing the validity of the file
file_test:
# Whether the file was provided as an argument
if [ $(file) = "" ]; then
    printf "${RED}ERROR${NC}: One & only file must be given in argument! Please specify it by:\nmake file=<file_name> <target>\n\n"; exit 1
fi

# Whether the file exists
if [ ! -f $(file) ]; then
    printf "$(RED)ERROR${NC}: $(file) File not found!\n\n"; exit 1
fi

# Whether the file is empty
if [ ! -s $(file) ]; then
    printf "$(RED)ERROR${NC}: $(file) is empty!\n\n"; exit 1
fi

# Whether it is a text file
if [[ ! "$(filetype)" = *"ASCII"* && ! "$(filetype)" = *"UTF-8"* ]]; then
    printf "$(RED)ERROR${NC}: Only text files (ASCII or UTF-8 Unicode text) are accepted!\n\n"; exit 1
fi


# Prints help on the useful targets for the user
help:
    printf "\n${CYAN}make file=<file_path>${NC} : Executes the simplification completely and avoids rebuilding if unnecessary.\n\n"
    printf "${CYAN}make file=<file_path> file_test${NC} : Tests whether the given file is valid.\n\n" 
    printf "${CYAN}make file=<file_path> NTS${NC} : Generates the corresponding NTS model result file.\n\n"
    printf "${CYAN}make file=<file_path> DSS${NC} : Generates the article's sentences split using the two semantic rules mentioned in the paper.\n\n"
    printf "${CYAN}make file=<file_path> tupa_parse${NC} : Parses the article's sentences using TUPA -> output : xml files.\n\n"
    printf "${CYAN}make file=<file_path> split_to_sentences${NC} : Splits the article into sentences, each one in a single file.\n\n"
    printf "${CYAN}make clean${NC} : Cleans results of previous executions.\n\n"


##############################################################################################


# Produces the simple version of text as an output and writes it to "article_simple" variable
$(article_simple): $(NTS_result_file)
    cd $(work_dir)
    cat $(NTS_result_file) > $(article_simple)


# Equivalent for target NTS
$(NTS_result_file): $(NTS_script) $(NTS_input)
    printf "\n${GREEN}Simplifying sentences using the NTS model : ... ${NC}\n\n"
    cd $(NTS_dir)/src/scripts/
    source ./translate.sh


# Equivalent for target DSS
$(NTS_input): $(script_dir)/split_sentences.py $(passages)
    printf "\n${GREEN}Splitting the article's sentences : ... ${NC}\n"
    python $(script_dir)/split_sentences.py $(passage_dir) > $(NTS_input)

# If the output of the splitting is empty, then it failed
if [ ! -s $(NTS_input) ]; then
    printf "$(RED)ERROR${NC}: Splitting failed!\n\n"; exit 1
fi


# Equivalent for target tupa_parse
$(passages): $(sentences) | $(passage_dir)
    printf "\n${GREEN}Parsing the article's sentences : ... ${NC}\n\n"
    python -m tupa $(sentences) -m $(work_dir)/TUPA_models/ucca-bilstm
    mv *.xml $(passage_dir)


# Equivalent for target split_to_sentences
$(sentences): $(file) $(script_dir)/article_to_sentences.py | $(sentence_dir)
    python $(script_dir)/article_to_sentences.py $(file)


# Creates the passage directory
$(passage_dir): $(file)
if [ -d $(passage_dir) ]; then
    rm -f $(passage_dir)/*.xml
else
    mkdir -p $(script_dir)/passages/
    mkdir $(passage_dir)/
fi


# Creates the sentence directory
$(sentence_dir): $(file)
if [ -d $(sentence_dir) ]; then
    rm -f $(sentence_dir)/*.txt
else
    mkdir -p $(script_dir)/sentences/
    mkdir $(sentence_dir)
fi


# Cleans the residues from previous executions
clean:
    rm -rf $(passage_dir)* $(sentence_dir)*
    echo > $(NTS_result_file)
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to delete TABs in a makefile.  Presumably that makefile worked fine for whomever wrote it, so going in and editing it is likely not going to help.  While it's possible that the content of the GitHub project is just broken, it's more likely that something is wrong in your environment or the way you ran the command, than it is that you need to edit their files to make them work.  So.  What operating system are you using?  What version of make are you using (`make --version`)?  What GitHub code are you trying to build?

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient.  I am using OS system, the make I am using is GNU Make 3.81, and the makefile that I am trying to run is from this Github(https://github.com/nzaim001/SENTS-reproduction) for an ACL paper.

Comment: I don't know what "OS system" is.  Did you mean MacOS?  The version of GNU make that comes with that system is old and probably buggy.  I cloned that repo to my GNU/Linux system and the makefile worked fine (anyway, it didn't give any sort of "unexpected end of file" error).  I don't have much access to MacOS but I recommend you use Homebrew to install a better version of GNU make and see if that helps: https://brew.sh/

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  I updated the make to be gmake, and it works!!  How exciting about that!